# two forloop in 1 table row

Tags: django

```
<table>
{% for sensie in teacher %}

<tr style='height:19px;'>
<th id="703183278R34" style="height: 19px;" class="row-headers-background">
<div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 19px;">35</div>
</th>

<td class="s46"></td>
<td class="s51" colspan="3">{{sensie.Subjects}}</td>
<td class="s51" colspan="4">{{sensie.Employee_Users}}</td>
{% endfor %}
{% for room in roomsched %}
<td class="s51" colspan="6">{{room.Classroom}}-{{room.Day_Name}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

\views

```
teacher = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(Education_Levels__in=studentenroll.values_list('Education_Levels'))
      roomsched = SubjectRoomSchedule.objects.filter(Subject_Section_Teacher__in=teacher)
return render(request, 'Homepage/enrollmentrecords.html',{,"teacher":teacher,"roomsched":roomsched})
```

how do i make it  properly formatted in table row just like this in the example shown below. please help me....

```
Subject            Teacher                Room
math             teachername             room512
```

here is my model,

```
class SubjectRoomSchedule(models.Model):
    Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Classroom =models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

class SubjectSectionTeacher(models.Model):
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    Courses= models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Sections= models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Subjects= models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Employee_Users= models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

Comment: You shouldn't fetch the rooms separately from the teachers. You should be able to traverse your relationships directly from a `sensie`, most likely. But you're not showing your models, so it's hard to say how your `sensie` relates to the room. Please read how to fetch objects from many-to-one and many-to-many relationships in the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: hi, sorry for short information, i already update my question. ahm can you show me your solution? cause icant understand what you saying, im new in django and web developing

Comment: So one `SubjectSectionTeacher` can have multiple `SubjectRoomSchedule` (i.e. multiple `Classroom`), which one do you want to display? all of them? In your example there's only one room.

Comment: Why do you have `related_name='+'` in each of your `ForeignKey`s?

Comment: i follow the tutorial thats why related_name='+', .. anyway i think my only error is not view but my template, my format in forloop

Comment: can you guys help me to correct my html table? please .. or maybe i have do wrong in my views?

Comment: sir dirkgroten, yes i just want to display "room" in SubjectRoomSchedule per SubjectSectionTeacher(Subjects and Employee_Users)

Answer (score 1):

Several issues with your markup:

- there must be as many `th` elements as there are columns (as many as `td`)
- the table header (the `th` elements) are of course outside the loop - the header is only displayed once
- you have to loop over rows therefore `tr` and all its child elements is in the loop, the rest must be outside
- you should not add cells dynamically to the row via an inner loop because the rows could contain different numbers of column counts then - therefore I changed your code to append the rooms to a comma separated list.

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Teacher</th>
        <th>Rooms</th>
      </tr>
    {% for sensie in teacher %}
      <tr style='height:19px;'>        
        <td class="s46"></td>
        <td class="s51" colspan="3">{{sensie.Subjects}}</td>
        <td class="s51" colspan="4">{{sensie.Employee_Users}}</td>
        <td class="s51" colspan="6">
        {% for room in roomsched %}
            {{room.Classroom}}-{{room.Day_Name}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: Room5-monday, room1-Tuesday, room1-monday i got this from <th>room</th> , per  teacher,

Comment: So your table is now displayed correctly - does that answer your original question? If new questions pop up afterwards you should either try to figure it out yourself or create a new question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Adding [`related_name='+'`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) means that you won't be able to use a reverse relation with your model, which surely is not what you want.

If you remove all the `related_name='+'` in your models, populating your template becomes much easier:

views.py:

```
teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(
                Education_Levels__in=studentenroll.values_list('Education_Levels')
           )
context = {"teachers":teachers}
return render(request, 'Homepage/enrollmentrecords.html', context)
```

Now in your template:

```
<table>
<th id="703183278R34" style="height: 19px;" class="row-headers-background">
<div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 19px;">35</div>
</th>
{% for teacher in teachers %}

<tr style="height:19px;"> 
<td class="s46"></td>
<td class="s51" colspan="3">{{teacher.Subjects}}</td>
<td class="s51" colspan="4">{{teacher.Employee_Users}}</td>
<td class="s51" colspan="6">
  {% for room in teacher.Subject_Section_Teacher_set.all %}
  {{room.Classroom}}-{{room.Day_Name}}
  {% endfor %}
</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
```

See [Risadinha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58379920/10746224) for an explanation on why your for loop wasn't working in the first place.

Comment: @marvin did you run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and `python3 manage.py migrate` after you changed your models?  You have to run this every time you change a model, if you want the changes to take place.

Comment: sir @Caleb, I already run makemigrations and migrate, but nothing happen

Comment: I already remove all "related_name='+'" in my model, follow all of your instructions.

Comment: @CalebGoodman while I totally support your suggestion - you have just copied the totally broken template markup in your answer to the question on how to fix the loop in the markup.

Comment: @Risadinha Thanks I didn't catch that, and I fixed it (I think).  I didn't exactly understand the question in the first place, so I wasn't thinking about the html.